# lxml Changing Unicode Characters

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using lxml to read through an xml file and change a few details. However, when running it I find that even if I just use lxml to read the file and then write it out again, as below:

```
fil='iTunes Music Library.XML'
tre=etree.parse(fil)
tre.write('temp.xml')
```

I find Queensrÿche converted to `Queensr&#255;che`. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```
tre.write('temp.xml', encoding='utf-8')
```

Otherwise `lxml` writes XML in ASCII encoding, so it have to escape all non-ASCII characters.