# Character encoding is violated

Tags: python, encoding, lxml

I am trying to parse a file encoded in `utf-8`. No operation has problem apart from write to file (or at least I think so). A minimum working example follows:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse('example.txt', parser)
tree.write('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.html')
```

example.txt:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <invalid html here/>
        <interesting attrib1="yes">
            <group>
                <line>
                    δεδομένα1
                </line>
            </group>
            <group>
                <line>
                    δεδομένα2
                </line>
            </group>
            <group>
                <line>
                    δεδομένα3
                </line>
            </group>
        </interesting>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am already aware of a [similar previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848371/lxml-changing-unicode-characters) but I could not solve the problem either without specifying the output encoding, or using `utf8` or `iso-8859-7`.

I have concluded that the file is in `utf8` since it displays correctly at Chrome when choosing this encoding. My editor (Kate) agrees.

I get no runtime error, but the output is not as desired.
Example output with `tree.write('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.html', encoding='utf-8')`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
        <invalid html="" here=""/><interesting attrib1="yes"><group><line>
                    Î´ÎµÎ´Î¿Î¼Î­Î½Î±1
                </line></group><group><line>
                    Î´ÎµÎ´Î¿Î¼Î­Î½Î±2
                </line></group><group><line>
                    Î´ÎµÎ´Î¿Î¼Î­Î½Î±3
                </line></group></interesting></body></html>
```

Comment: What error do you get, and how do you get it? Please post the code that breaks and the error it gives. The question you linked tells you that `lxml` writes everything in ASCII unless you tell it not to; have you tried `tree.write(<file>,encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: I edited the question. I get no runtime error. Unfortunately, the output is not encoded properly as you can see.

Comment: I don't know this library, but maybe you have to specify the input encoding as well (it may default to ASCII, or your local default encoding). Why, btw, are you using an invalid HTML document for this example?

Comment: Thanks! It was the input encoding. It appears that `lxml` uses the encoding denoted by the first line of the file (if missing then uses `ascii`). I could not specify it in the program, but when I appended a line at the beginning of the file with the right encoding, it worked. Btw, I used invalid html to denote that I have to use lxml and not another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem is that HTMLParser treats the input file as ANSI by default, i.e. the UTF-8 bytes are misinterpreted as 8-bit character codes. You can simply pass the encoding to fix this:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding = "utf-8")
```

If you want to check what I meant with the misinterpretation, let Python print `repr(tree.xpath("//line")[0].text)` with and without HTMLParser's `encoding` parameter.